# R code challenge: retrieving the values in matching columns and sum them up with matching rows

Tags: r

I have a problem solving this in R. I have this data frame called testa (dput included). I need to match all the letters in column `ALT` with the colnames `(A,C,G,T,N)` and get the corresponding values in those column along with the value for `REF` letters and get the result `ad.new` (my code does this job).

However, I need to expand this code to solve an issue with the line where the `TYPE` column has `flat` at the end. For the row with the `flat`, I need to match its start id (`chr10:102053031`) with other ids in start column. If they match, I need to sum up the corresponding value for `ALT` from `A,C,G,T,N` column and replace it with ad.new column for the flat line along with the `REF` value.

If you run the `dput` and my code you will be able to understand it. So basically, I want to match the letters in `REF` and `ALT` columns and get the corresponding values from the columns (`A,C,G,T,N`) and separate those values by comma for `REF` and `ALT`. However (in this example), for `flat` line I want to sum up the value in column `A` with matching start id with the start id of `flat` line (the value in this case is `6`) and the value with another match (the value in this case is `7` from `G` column) and sum them together to give `13`. So for flat line my result should be `0,13`.

The expected result is also shown below.

my incomplete code:

```
testa[is.na(testa)]<-0 
ref.counts<-testa[,testa[,"REF"]]
ref.counts<-as.matrix(Ref.counts) 
ref.counts[is.na(Ref.counts)]<-0
ref.counts<-diag(Ref.counts)

alt.counts<-testa[,testa[,"ALT"]]
alt.counts<-as.matrix(alt.counts)
alt.counts[is.na(alt.counts)]<-0
alt.counts<-diag(alt.counts)

#############
##need to extend this code here
#############
ad.new<-paste(Ref.counts,alt.counts,sep=",")
```

dput for testa:

```
structure(c("chr10:101544447", "chr10:102053031", "chr10:102778767", 
"chr10:102789831", "chr10:102989480", "chr10:102053031", "chr10:102053031", 
"0", "6", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "34", "24", "0", "0", 
"34", "34", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "7", "53", "0", "0", 
"30", "12", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", 
"0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", 
"chr10", "chr10", "chr10", "chr10", "chr10", "chr10", "chr10", 
"101544447", "102053031", "102778767", "102789831", "102989480", 
"102053031", "102053031", "A", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", 
"T", "A", "T", "T", "T", "G", "G", "snp", "snp", "snp", "snp", 
"snp", "snp:102053031:flat", "snp", "nonsynonymous SNV", 
"intronic", "nonsynonymous SNV", "nonsynonymous SNV", "ncRNA_exonic", 
"intronic", "intronic", "ABCC2:NM_000392:exon2:c.A116T:p.Y39F,", 
"PKD2L1", "PDZD7:NM_024895:exon8:c.G1136A:p.R379Q,PDZD7:NM_001195263:exon8:c.G1136A:p.R379Q,", 
"PDZD7:NM_024895:exon2:c.G146A:p.R49Q,PDZD7:NM_001195263:exon2:c.G146A:p.R49Q,", 
"LBX1-AS1", "PKD2L1", "PKD2L1"), .Dim = c(7L, 15L), .Dimnames = list(
    c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7"), c("start", "A", "C", 
    "G", "T", "N", "=", "-", "chr", "end", "REF", "ALT", "TYPE", 
    "refGene::location", "refGene::type")))
```

Expected result

```
 ad.new
"0,53"
"34,6"
"24,0"
"0,30"
"0,12"
"0,13" 
"34,7"
```

Comment: Can you clarify the rules for the flat line? Why would I select the values in "A" and "G" if they are not specified anywhere?

Comment: A and G are the letters in ALT column in 2nd and last rows (rows that match with the start  id chr10:102053031 for the flat line  ("snp:102053031:flat") in TYPE column). So the flat line should have sum of ALT values . 'start' column is the chromosome number and the gene locations and th flat line is basically the sum of all the gene locations (matching ids in the start column). Thank you!

Comment: Technically the ALT column for the flat line should have both A and G letters that are in other two matching rows (hence I need the sum in my result), but in our genetics requirements we only mention the most common one(or the dominant one) which is G in this case.

Comment: So it will always be the sum of the values in the "A" column and all the values from whichever other column has the most non-zero values, as grouped by "end"?

Comment: Not always the A column. The start id in flat line matches with other two rows and their ALT letters ar A and G in this case whose corresponding values are 6 and 7 respectively. There are numerous flat lines and each of those flat lines will have multiple other matching rows (generally two rows for each flat row). I think I need a function to get the ALT letters and their corresponding values for the rows that matches with the start id of flat line and ultimately sum them up.

Comment: I would suggest that you create another smaller example with only the columns of interest, and with one or two test cases for flat lines. It would make it easier for others to gauge what is going on.

Comment: So first, I need to identify the flat line, get the start id. Match that id to find other matching rows and retrieve their ALT letter and then their corresponding numerical values from A,C,G,T,N columns and finally sum those values for the flat line to be placed along with the REF value in the result.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/82174/discussion-between-user277653-and-ananda-mahto).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this should work :

```
# apply the "normal" rule (non considering flat exceptions)
alts <- as.numeric(diag(testa[,testa[,"ALT"]]))
refs <- as.numeric(diag(testa[,testa[,"REF"]]))
res <- paste(refs,alts,sep=",")

# replace lines having TYPE ending with "flat"
flats <- grep('.*flat$',testa[,"TYPE"])
res[flats] <- 
unlist(lapply(flats,function(x){
                startId <- testa[x,"start"]
                selection <- setdiff(which(testa[,"start"] == startId),r)
                paste0("0,",sum(alts[selection]))
             }))

ad.new <- as.matrix(res)
> ad.new
     [,1]  
[1,] "0,53"
[2,] "34,6"
[3,] "24,0"
[4,] "0,30"
[5,] "0,12"
[6,] "0,13"
[7,] "34,7"
```

Comment: Thank you, this is the best way to do the job I need!